# How do I use font cls files in LaTeX

Tags: fonts

How do I install fonts into latex in `ubuntu 16.04`?

The template, `deedy-resume` that I am trying to use requires `XeTeX` to compile and `fontspec` is throwing errors. The font files I have are `.ttf` format. I have put the `.cls` file in the same directory as my `.tex` document.

I found the root folder `/usr/local/share/texmf` and `sudo cp` the `.ttf` files in there but that doesn't seem to work? I also tried copying the `.ttf` files into `~/.fonts/` with the folder structure `~/.fonts/font1/*.ttf`, `~/.fonts/font2/*.ttf` and that doesn't work either.

I made this small snippet:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\begin{document}

\namesection{Whos}{Who}{ \urlstyle{same}\href{http://example.io}{MEEEEE}\\
\href{mailto:email@gmail.com}{email@gmail.com}
}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth} 

\section{Education} 

\subsection{University}
\descript{Degree}
\descript{Degree}
\location{Dec 2016 | Virginia}
\sectionsep

\end{minipage} 
\end{document}
```

The fonts I put in `/user/share/fonts/truetype` as per the comments.

Comment: (1) texmaker is not related to this issue (2) please explain how fonts and cls files are associated. In short, please explain what iøyou have and what you are trying to do. As your question is now it is very unclear

Comment: "how do I install fonts into latex in ubuntu 16.04?" if the font is installed on your system in the normal way, XeTeX should be able to find it. It should probably be in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/`. If it's there, and something's not working, your problem is probably with the way you're trying to use XeTeX, rather than the font being improperly installed. Please provide [a full MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Try this: (1) In Terminal, `mktexlsr` just in case you manually placed a file and forgot to update TeX. That's probably not the problem. (2) What happens if you place a copy of the fonts directly in the same folder as your main `*.tex` document?

Comment: This cannot be answered properly without a link to the class and (possibly or) the text of the error message you receive. We don't even know which fonts you have or why those are the ones you think the class wants.

Comment: @RobtAll `mktexlsr` isn't relevant for system-installed fonts. If the problem was of that kind, `mktexlsr` wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: Usually, one just downloads the template, unzips if necessary, and it works. Problem with fonts only occur if people move files around.

Comment: Usually meaning: People used the initial template, modified it in some way without marking the changes and uploaded it without any note that the template was changed. This template is one of this kind and without knowing which specific template you are using, we cannot answer the question. Of course, just moving the font to where the system can find it should solve your problem.